# JQuery select checkboxes with the same value

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in JQuery to check checkboxes based on their value.

e.g. if I have 3 checkboxes with the value 'test' is there any way I can check them all based just on the fact that they have the value 'test'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox[value=test]").attr("checked", true);
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GNJ6t/

EDIT:

jQuery 1.6 introduces the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method, which is the supposed best way of achieving the above. From the manual:

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead
>   of the .attr() method.

So:

```
$(":checkbox[value=test]").prop("checked", true);
```